# Handle data changes in BI and Data warehouse systems

Tags: data-analysis, splunk, splunk-dbconnect

We are adopting Splunk> as a BI solution with the aiming of ingesting SQL Data directly into SPLUNK> and bring powerfull reports/dashboards to the User.

The question that I have in general is how to handle data changes in a BI system and ensure that we always have the same state with the source.

How do you handle data changes:

- Data changes that happen in the source system?
- Data Deletions that happen in the source system ?

Is there any general approach for tackling this kind of issues ?

Answer (score 1):

Let me say up front that Splunk is not a replacement for SQL databases.  Each have their own roles to play.

Splunk supports ingestion of SQL data using its DB Connect add-on.  DB Connect executes SQL queries and indexes the results.  New and changed DB rows become new events in Splunk indexes.

There is no deleting of indexed data in Splunk, even if the data disappears from the source.  The only way events are removed from Splunk is when they age out or they need to be deleted to make room for new events.